# javascript jszip add file to each loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, text, jszip

hello i am having trouble with my loop using jszip - 
this is for replacing text, i'm planning to do 1000 files or more. 
what i want is to add a number i++ to each and save it to a seperate text file in the zip. but now my code is like this and it only shows the last file with the input text- please help

i want the zip.add to loop through each variation- but it only writes the number not the whole input+number

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jszip.js"></script>
<form>
<label> Enter Block of text </label>
<textarea id="inp" name="original"></textarea>
<label> Here is your result </label> 
<textarea id="out" name="result"></textarea>

<label> Enter string to replace </label> <br>
<input type="text" id="ori" name="string"></input>
<label> Enter what to replace it with </label> 
<input type="text" id="new" name="replace"></input>
<input type="button" onClick="getin()" value="Click for result">
<input id="button" type="button" onClick="getzip()" value="Create Zip">    </input> </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var zip = new JSZip();

for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    getin(i) 
    }

function getin() {
    var old = document.getElementById("ori").value;
    var reg = new RegExp(old, "gim" );
    var e = document.getElementById("new").value;
    var str1, str2;
    str1 = document.getElementById("inp").value;
    if (str1 == "") {null;}
    var end = str1.replace (reg, e+i);
    document.getElementById("out").value = end;
     zip.add("output"+i+".txt", end+"\n")
    }

    function getzip ()     {
    content=zip.generate();
    location.href="data:application/zip;base64,"+content;   
}
```

Comment: `getin(i)` in for loop but you function `getin()` doesn't take any arguments

Comment: i want this to loop    `zip.add("output"+i+".txt", end+"\n")`

Comment: also how can i make the #out id display the result without clicking  - i think this is the answer

Comment: also   `var end = str1.replace (reg, e+i);`

Answer (score 0):

This will create a zip with 100 files with different outputs based on your regex replace - not sure what you wanted to happen with the content exactly.

```js
var zip;

function getin() {
  var old = document.getElementById("ori").value;
  var reg = new RegExp(old, "gim");
  var e = document.getElementById("new").value;
  var str1, str2;
  str1 = document.getElementById("inp").value;
  if (str1 == "") {
    return;
  }
  
  zip = new JSZip();
  var result = '';
  
  Array(100).fill().forEach(function(v,i) {  
   var end = str1.replace(reg, e + i);
   result += end;
   zip.file("output" + i + ".txt", end + "\n")
  });
  
  document.getElementById("out").value = result;
}


function getzip() {
  if (!zip) { return; }
  content = zip.generate();
  location.href = "data:application/zip;base64," + content;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://rawgit.com/Stuk/jszip/master/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <label> Enter Block of text </label>
  <textarea id="inp" name="original"></textarea>
  <label> Here is your result </label>
  <textarea id="out" name="result"></textarea>

  <label> Enter string to replace </label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="ori" name="string">
  <label> Enter what to replace it with </label>
  <input type="text" id="new" name="replace">
  <input type="button" onClick="getin()" value="Click for result">
  <input id="button" type="button" onClick="getzip()" value="Create Zip">
</form>
```